# How to set a TbButtonColumn's visibility depending on a database field?

Tags: php, database, yii, cgridview

How do I make my TbButtonColumn invisible based on a database field? My buttons are placed inside a CGridView. The buttons should be hidden if a certain field is empty. But I can't seem to make it work. Can anyone help me? Thank you! Here are my codes:

cGridViewPending.php

```
'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{updateView}{updateView2}',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'updateView'=>
                array(
                    'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("SendEmail", array("id"=>$data["id_schedule"]))',
                    'label'=>'Approve',
                    'visible'=>$this->fetchRemarks(), //this is where I am calling the function to hide the button.
                    'click'=>'function(){return confirm("Are you sure you want to approve this reservation? It is highly recommended to put a remark before approving this reservation request.");}',
                    'options' => array (
                        'class'=>'btn btn-medium btn-success',
                        'icon'=>'icon-circle-arrow-right',
                    ),
                ),
```

ScheduleController.php

```
public function fetchRemarks()
{
    $id = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('id');
    $dataModel = Schedule::model()->findByPk($id);

    //Remarks
    $checkRemarks = "SELECT remarks FROM schedule WHERE id_schedule = $dataModel;
    $x = Yii::app()->reservation_db
        ->createCommand($checkRemarks)
        ->queryScalar();

    if ($x = null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Solved! Thanks to tinybyte! Here's how I did it, for the sake of others that will encounter the same problem.

```
'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("SendEmail", array("id"=>$data["id_schedule"]))',
                    'label'=>'Approve',
                    'visible'=>function($row_number, $model){
                            if ($model->remarks == 0) //the 'remarks' is my basis for the visibility of the TbButtonColumn.
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'updateView'=>
            array(
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("SendEmail", array("id"=>$data["id_schedule"]))',
                'label'=>'Approve',
                'visible'=>function($row_number, $data){ // $data is your model record

                        // here check whether to show the button or not
                        return false; //not show this button
                    },
```

Comment: what should i do about the $row_number @tinybyte ?

Comment: oh wait i get it now! thank you so much! i'll manipulate the code to suit my needs. thank you!